# Matching columns and finding the unmatched value

Tags: r, matching

`df <- data.frame(A = c('100, 200, 300, 100', '100, 200', '100, 200, 300'),  B = c('100, 200, 300', '100, 200, 300', '100, 200'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`
I have a data frame example here
[image: New Data]

I have to do a comparison, the result of which can be found in column 'Flag.' If it's a perfect match, then Flag will be Y. Otherwise N. If the Flag is N, then I've to determine what the missing value is. Taking Row #2 as an example: 300 is missing from Column A, so I populate that under Value A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty messy but it will get what you want.

```
library(dplyr)
  df1 <- data.frame(
    A = c("100,200,300", "100,200", "100,200,400"),
    B = c("100,200,300", "100,200,300", "100,200")
  )
  isEmpty <- function(x) {
    return(length(x)==0)
  }
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(A = as.character(A),
         B = as.character(B)) %>%
  mutate(Flag = ifelse(A == B, "Y", "N"))

df2 <- apply(df1, 1, function(x){
  if (x[3] == "N"){
    a <- x[1] %>% strsplit(., ",") %>% unlist %>% as.numeric()
    b <- x[2] %>% strsplit(., ",") %>% unlist %>% as.numeric()
    val_A <- ifelse(isEmpty(setdiff(a,b)), "A", setdiff(a,b))
    val_B <- ifelse(isEmpty(setdiff(b,a)), "A", setdiff(b,a))
    c(val_A,val_B)
  } else {
    c(NA,NA)
  }
}) %>% t %>% as.data.frame() %>% dplyr::rename(Value_A = V1, Value_B = V2)
cbind(df1, df2)

            A           B Flag Value_A Value_B
1 100,200,300 100,200,300    Y    <NA>    <NA>
2     100,200 100,200,300    N       A     300
3 100,200,400     100,200    N     400       A
```

Comment: The "Flag" column also we have to create. The logic would be that if Column A matches with Column B values , it's "Y" otherwise "N". Can you help with that as well

Comment: @PInitiate I edit my code above. I apologize that I didn't notice that.

Comment: There is an error in the line  df1 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(Flag = ifelse(A == B, "Y", "N"))

Comment: @PInitiate Oh...Did you use `dplyr`?

Comment: Yes, I have installed the Library for that.

Comment: df1 <- df1 %>%
+   mutate(Flag = ifelse(A == B, "Y", "N"))
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Flag`.
x level sets of factors are different
i Input `Flag` is `ifelse(A == B, "Y", "N")`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: This error is there.

Comment: @PInitiate Can you give me the result for `str(df1)`?

Comment: str(df1)
'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ A: Factor w/ 3 levels "100,200","100,200,300",..: 2 1 3
 $ B: Factor w/ 2 levels "100,200","100,200,300": 2 2 1

Comment: @PInitiate It's strange that `A` thing and `B` things are factor. I edit code above.

Comment: df2 <- apply(df1, 1, function(x){
+   if (x[3] == "N"){
+     a <- x[1] %>% strsplit(., ",") %>% unlist %>% as.numeric()
+     b <- x[2] %>% strsplit(., ",") %>% unlist %>% as.numeric()
+     val_A <- ifelse(isEmpty(setdiff(a,b)), "A", setdiff(a,b))
+     val_B <- ifelse(isEmpty(setdiff(b,a)), "A", setdiff(b,a))
+     c(val_A,val_B)
+   } else {
+     c(NA,NA)
+   }
+ }) %>% t %>% as.data.frame() %>% dplyr::rename(Value_A = V1, Value_B = V2)
Error in if (x[3] == "N") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: @PInitiate I removed `df1 <- `  in `mutate` part before. I edit it now. Would you mind to try again?

Comment: @PInitiate I'm really sorry for your inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

You can split column A and column B on comma and compare them to get the output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(A:B, strsplit, ',\\s*'), 
         Flag = map2_chr(A, B, ~if(all(.x %in% .y) && all(.y %in% .x)) 'Y' else 'N'),
         ColumnA = map2_chr(A, B, ~toString(setdiff(.y, .x))), 
         ColumnB = map2_chr(A, B, ~toString(setdiff(.x, .y))))

#              A             B Flag ColumnA ColumnB
#1 100, 200, 300 100, 200, 300    Y                
#2      100, 200 100, 200, 300    N     300        
#3 100, 200, 300      100, 200    N             300
```

For this example, to get `Flag` column we can just do `Flag = ifelse(A == B, 'Y', 'N')` but what if you have values like `100, 200, 300` and `300, 200, 100` in that case `ifelse` would return `'N'` and hence I have preferred to split and compare.

---

For the updated data where the count is important as well, we may use `vsetdiff` function from `vecsets` package.

```
library(vecsets)

df %>%
  mutate(across(A:B, strsplit, ',\\s*'), 
         Flag = map2_chr(A, B, ~if(all(.x %in% .y) && all(.y %in% .x)) 'Y' else 'N'),
         ColumnA = map2_chr(A, B, ~toString(vsetdiff(.y, .x))), 
         ColumnB = map2_chr(A, B, ~toString(vsetdiff(.x, .y))))
```

Comment: Throws an error for me .  Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x non-character argument
i Input `..1` is `across(A:B, strsplit, ",\\s*")`.

Comment: Most probably you are on R < 4.0.0 in which case you need to add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `data.frame` call above if you are using the data from my answer. Also as mentioned it is helpful if you provide a reproducible example so we can adjust our answers according to your actual data. Adding data as an image is not helpful to debug the issue.

Comment: Should I add it to the code?

Comment: I have edited the dataframe. Can you suggest why the code gives "Y" when the 1st cells are not matching for column A and column B?

Comment: That is because both A and B have 100, 200 and 300. Do you also want to match the count of those values ? Would the numbers always be in the same order ? In that case using `Flag = ifelse(A == B, 'Y', 'N')` would solve the issue.

Comment: The matching is fine. But, can suggest an edit to return the value "100" which is not available in the second column first cell in the "Value_A" column?

Comment: I have added the new figure; can you help now?

Comment: We can use `vsetdiff` from `vecsets` package. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Your code helps. I have another issue; when I have values like 100, 200, 300, 100 in A and 300, 200, 100 in B, in that case, your code gives me the Flag value as "Y," but I want it to be "N". How can I solve that?